# How to track multiple Contact Form 7 forms individually using GTM in GA4?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, google-analytics

I am currently working on a project where I need to track multiple Contact Form 7 forms individually on a WordPress website using Google Tag Manager (GTM) and Google Analytics 4 (GA4). I have already set up GTM and GA4 on my website, but I'm facing challenges in implementing the tracking for each form separately.

Here's the problem:

**Multiple Forms**: I have 5-6 Contact Form 7 forms on different pages of my website, and I need to track each of them individually. Each form serves a different purpose and is on a unique page.

**Custom Event Tracking**: GA4 doesn't natively track form submissions like Universal Analytics, so I need to implement custom event tracking for each form using GTM.

**Unique Identifiers**: Each form has a unique identifier, either a form ID or a CSS selector, which I can use to distinguish them.

I have tried to follow online guides and examples, but I'm having trouble creating custom GTM triggers and tags for each form and ensuring that the data is sent to GA4 accurately. I'm looking for a step-by-step solution with code examples that can help me achieve this tracking.

Could someone please provide a detailed guide on how to set up GTM and GA4 to track each Contact Form 7 form individually? Specifically, I need assistance with creating custom JavaScript variables, triggers, and tags for each form, and ensuring that the data is correctly sent to GA4.